# Which WEKA output option from command-line, works with WEKA Experiment Environment Analyse?

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification, weka, osx-mavericks

I am running the following command from the command line:

```
java -cp "./weka.jar" weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t ./WEKA_reference_test_set.arff -i > test.arff
```

I want to be able to take my output results file, `test.arff` , and analyse the data in WEKA's GUI environment. Why? My experiments will eventually be run on a cluster which needs to output to a format where I can access the same amount of results data, as I would be able to from the GUI environment (the GUI, of course, not be available on the cluster). Specifically I am trying to get to the results for each fold of the classifier, upon doing cross-validation on the data. WEKA runs fine and performs the classification as instructed (I have checked the results by storing them in a csv file), so there is no problem there.

Currently I am getting the following error when trying to load my results file in the WEKA GUI environment:

[image: ARFF file fail]

Any ideas?

This is running on OS X with WEKA version 3.6.10 (latest stable release).

Answer (score 0):

This will give you limited results, not as extensive as running your experiment through the GUI, but it works.

```
java -cp "./weka.jar" weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t ./WEKA_reference_test_set.arff  -threshold-file test.arff
```